# Expand/Contract Table Section using AngularJS

Tags: dom, angularjs

I have an HTML table that is bound to data via AngularJS.  To make it simple, let's just say it has two columns, CustomerId and CustomerName.

When a user clicks on the row (or a plus sign, button, link, doesn't matter), I would like to expand a section below the row, make an ajax call, and display the resulting data.  I would also like to collapse the previously expanded row, if any.

This seems like a DOM manipulation task, and I know how to do it in JQuery (or at least can figure it out), but I'd like to do it properly (i.e. "the Angular Way").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually a bit difficult to do with Angular today, but you have a couple of options.

First, I think the most declarative solution would be to have a `<tr>` with the normal state, and a `<tr>` with the edit state:

```html
<tr ng-show="edit"><td><input ng-model="model.name" ...
<tr ng-hide="edit"><td>{{model.name}} ...
```

the alternative (which actually is simpler) is to do this on the column `<td>`

```html
<tr>
  <td ng-show="edit"><input ng-model="model.name" ... 
  <td ng-hide="edit">{{model.name}} ... 
</tr>
```

The reason this is simpler is that in the current version (1.0.x) of Angular you can only do `ng-repeat` on a single root element (although it looks like this will get changed in v 1.2.x: [multi-element directives](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e46100f7097d9a8f174bdb9e15d4c6098395c3f2)). Fortunately you're allowed to use multiple `<tbody>` tags in html, so this is actually valid:

```html
<tbody ng-repeat="model in models"> 
  <tr ng-show="edit"><td><input ng-model="model.name" ...
  <tr ng-hide="edit"><td>{{model.name}} ...
<tbody>
```

Note that using `ng-hide` only hides the element from the dom. If you're concerned about performance (huge tables or mobile devices) `ng-switch` (or `ng-if` in 1.2.x) might be a better option as it removes the hidden part from the dom:

```html
  <tbody ng-repeat="model in models" ng-switch="row.edit" ng-init="row={}">
    <tr ng-switch-when="true">
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="model.customerId" disabled /></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="model.customerName" /></td>
      <td ng-click="row.edit=false">done</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-switch-default>
      <td>{{model.customerId}}</td>
      <td>{{model.customerName}}</td>
      <td ng-click="row.edit=true">edit</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

**Update**: I've added a third solution which uses ng-include:

This method is maybe not the most declarative, but it works pretty good. I've created two different row templates (these can be separate files or inlined as ng-templates as in my example), and then I use `ng-include` to switch between the two templates. Note that this works without the additional `<tbody>`:

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" charset="utf-8" id="display.html">
  <td>{{model.customerId}}</td>
  <td>{{model.customerName}}</td>
  <td ng-click="row.edit=true">edit</td>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" charset="utf-8" id="edit.html">
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="model.customerId" disabled /></td>
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="model.customerName" /></td>
  <td ng-click="row.edit=false">done</td>
</script>

<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>CustomerId</th>
    <th>CustomerName</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="model in models" 
      ng-include="{true:'edit.html',false:'display.html'}[row.edit]" 
      ng-init="row={edit:false}"></tr>
</table>
```

I've created a simple example using ng-switch and ng-show/hide: http://plnkr.co/edit/6kBPIT0Z07ti4BtnGrXj

Comment: Fantastic!  I went with the ng-switch option.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through directives. DOM manipulation is generally done through directives.
http://plnkr.co/edit/0Z36Q3EEvP9GElzuAe5M

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
        angular.module('App').directive(
                'tab', ['$http',
                    function ($http) {
                        return {
                            template: '<table border="1" ng-click="click();show=!show" ><tr >' +
                                    '<th >ID</th>' + '<th>customer</th>' +
                                    ' </tr>' +
                                    '<tr ng-show="show" ng-repeat="data in datas"><td>{{data[0]}}</td><td>'+
                                    '{{data[1]}}</td></tr>' +
                                    '</table><br/>',
                            restrict: 'A',
                            link: function postLink(scope,element) {
                                scope.show =false;
                                scope.click = function () {
                                    //console.log(scope.datas);
                                    if (scope.datas ==null) {
                                        $http.get('/data').success(function (data) {
                                            scope.datas =data;
                                        }).error(function () {
                                          scope.datas = [[1,"i am customer 1"],[3,"i am customer 2"]];
                                        })
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    }
                ]);
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="App">
<div tab></div>
</body>
```